# How to setup Testnet in Windows?

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, windows

What are the commands for windows power shell to make a testnet. I require steps to set up testnet in private network in Windows OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article has steps to setup private testnet.

https://arctouch.com/blog/how-to-set-up-ethereum-blockchain/

There is no difference in "geth" commands between windows and Linux.